# Using Jedis pool in JAX-RS app running in Quarkus native results in ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.DefaultEvictionPolicy

Tags: jax-rs, jedis, quarkus

I'm trying to use `JedisPool` in application run in Quarkus native mode (works fine in JVM mode).
I've already disabled JMX feature of the pool, which is not avaliable in native mode, like this:

```
  JedisPoolConfig jedisConfiguration = new JedisPoolConfig();
  jedisConfiguration.setJmxEnabled(false);
  jedisPool = new JedisPool(jedisConfiguration, jedisURI);
```

However I'm hitting following error:

```
2020-04-29 17:35:37,724 INFO  [test.StockQuote] (main) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.EvictionPolicy instance of type org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.DefaultEvictionPolicy
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.BaseGenericObjectPool.setEvictionPolicyClassName(BaseGenericObjectPool.java:662)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.BaseGenericObjectPool.setEvictionPolicyClassName(BaseGenericObjectPool.java:687)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.BaseGenericObjectPool.setConfig(BaseGenericObjectPool.java:235)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.setConfig(GenericObjectPool.java:302)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.<init>(GenericObjectPool.java:115)
    at redis.clients.jedis.util.Pool.initPool(Pool.java:45)
    ...
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.DefaultEvictionPolicy
    at com.oracle.svm.core.hub.ClassForNameSupport.forName(ClassForNameSupport.java:60)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(DynamicHub.java:1197)
```

as a temporary solution, I switched to create direct connection instead of using pool, but still looking for possibility of using pool.

Any suggestions or workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I dug a little more and found this more info about `Class.forName` on these pages: [Reflection on Substrate VM](https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/substratevm/REFLECTION.md) and [Quarkus - Tips for writing native applications](https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips)
and found a solution via `reflection-config.json` file which contains:

```
[
  {
    "name" : "org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.DefaultEvictionPolicy",
    "allDeclaredConstructors" : true,
    "allPublicConstructors" : true,
    "allDeclaredMethods" : true,
    "allPublicMethods" : true,
    "allDeclaredFields" : true,
    "allPublicFields" : true
  }
]
```

You need also add following line to your `application.properties` file:

```
quarkus.native.additional-build-args =-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=reflection-config.json
```

Then my application runs successfully.